# Firefox doesn't retain form values when going back

Tags: html, spring-mvc, firefox, thymeleaf

I have a problem in Spring MVC with a simple search form. When the user is on the result page and goes back, the previous input data should be displayed in the form. This should only happen when the users goes back, so if he refresh the page the form inputs should be cleared. This works automatically for IE, Safari and Chrome. Unfortunately not for Firefox. Has anybody an idea? How can i fix this?

Here is the corresponding method in the controller:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = BFunctions.WA_SEARCH, method = RequestMethod.GET)    
public ModelAndView searchForm() {
    SearchDto searchDto = new SearchDto();
    return new ModelAndView("/search", "entity", searchDto);
}
```

And my html template using thymeleaf:

```
 <form class="form-horizontal search" role="form" method="get" th:action="@{${currentUser}? ${BFunctions.WA_SEARCH_RESULTS} : '/public/search/results'}" th:object="${entity}">
    <form:group name="name" class="auto-focus-primary" th:text="#{search.name}" />
    <form:group name="street" th:text="#{search.street}" />
    ......
    </form>
```

Comment: Define what you mean by "goes back"... do you mean they click the back-button on the browser, or do you mean they're redirected back to the page through a link/button/etc?

Comment: I mean click the back-button on the browser.

Comment: Then I think you're out of luck... it's highly unlikely you'll be able to override the default behaviour of a browser in this situation